# Hide a li if then inner content also empty

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I have the following html

```
<li class="item product product-item category">
  <div class="product-item-info">
    <div class="product details product-item-details">
      <strong class="product name product-item-name">
        <a class="product-item-link" href="stackexchange.com">content</a>
      </strong>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>



<li class="item product product-item category">
  <div class="product-item-info">
    <div class="product details product-item-details">
      <strong class="product name product-item-name">
        <a class="product-item-link" href="stackexchange.com"></a>
      </strong>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Here the second `<li>` is empty , because inside the `.product-item-link` the content is none. How can I hide this `<li>` ?

I need Javascript or CSS method to hide this . I cant mention it is second `<li>` , because there are so many `<li>` in my HTML and for writing here I just take this two `<li>` only.

Comment: anything you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you support major browsers, then you can use [`closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method

```
document.querySelector(".product-item-link:empty")
   .closest(".product-item").style.display = 'none';
```

```js
document.querySelector(".product-item-link:empty")
  .closest(".product-item").style.display = 'none';
```

```css
ol { background: #ff9999;padding: 20px;}ol li {background: #ffe5e5;padding: 10px;margin-left: 15px;}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="item product product-item category">
    <div class="product-item-info">
      <div class="product details product-item-details">
        <strong class="product name product-item-name">
  <a class="product-item-link" href="stackexchange.com">content</a>
  </strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>


  <li class="item product product-item category">
    <div class="product-item-info">
      <div class="product details product-item-details">
        <strong class="product name product-item-name">
  <a class="product-item-link" href="stackexchange.com"></a>
  </strong>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: also how can i select using product link or content . example <a hrer="123.html">hello</a> . How can i select based on 123.html & hello .

Comment: You mean to say if `.product-item-link` href attribute is empty, then also hide the `li`?

Comment: actually your answer is correct . But i am asking another question . Like how can i select an element if its href is  123.html

Comment: You can use `document.querySelector("a[href='123.html']")`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```js
$("li.item").each(function(){
  if ($(this).find('a.product-item-link').text()=="") {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="list">
    <li class="item product product-item category">
      <div class="product-item-info">
      <div class="product details product-item-details">
      <strong class="product name product-item-name">
      <a class="product-item-link" href="stackexchange.com">content</a>
      </strong>
      </div>
      </div>
    </li> 

    <li class="item product product-item category">
      <div class="product-item-info">
      <div class="product details product-item-details">
      <strong class="product name product-item-name">
      <a class="product-item-link" href="stackexchange.com"></a>
      </strong>
      </div>
      </div>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

### Edit: Using JavaScript

```
var li = document.getElementById("list").getElementsByTagName("li"); 
  for(i=0;i<li.length;i++) {
    var content = li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerText; 
    if (content == "") {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    } 
  }
```

Comment: is there is any javascript equivalent for this code . i can't use jquery

Comment: Okay, I will add the JavaScript code

Answer (score 0):

You should write a JavaScript function to:

1. Get all `<li>` in an array
2. Loop over the array
3. Add a 'hidden' class to `<li>` with no value / text content
4. Add the 'hidden' class to your css with properties that can hide `<li>` (ie opacity)